# A metal song on season 3 episode 3 of Boku no Hero Academia where the villains are starting in the wood

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

There's a song which starts at 21:20 at season 3 episode 3 of *Boku no Hero Academia* where the villains are starting in the wood. It sounds like metal.

What is the name of the song?

Comment: Related? [What is the metal song called which is played at 20:35 in Boku no Hero Academia season 3 episode 3?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/46845) (not yet answered)

Answer (score 0):

Vanguard Action Squad -All-out Attack-

The full soundtrack just got released. You can listen to all of it here:
https://youtu.be/Js7BIXiHQ8I

Song starts at 1:17:53.